# treejack tree-test - pages that are not in main navigation (access from in-page links)

Tags: navigation, information-architecture, tree, sitemap

I'm planning a tree test using Treejack. I'm testing the current nav structure of a site to gain insight before re-designing the site including nav and structure.

The site in question has ~150 pages. ~30 of those are not in the current navigation hierarchy, but are accessed via on-page links within page content. Some are linked to from multiple pages.

Question is **how could I represent these in the tree test? What is you experience with similar structures?**

For info, the top horizontal nav is used for for level 1, left nav for levels 2, 3, 4.

Comment: why aren't those 30 links in the navigation hierarchy? any reason for them to not be?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the strict situation you've described, without asking questions about alternatives to finding that content, I'd recommend you register people selecting the page in Treejack on which the content is linked to as a 'success' for them finding that content.

If you at all expect or want the user to navigate to subsequent pages, however, or re-orient themselves back onto the path that lead to that content, then I'd recommend placing it within a larger structure.

I find it often helps to ask the following:

- if a user begins on this page (say, coming in from search), how will they understand its context?
- in that same scenario, how might the user return to this page via a different means? (directly, vs via search)